# How to convert a string to html and add a event, descard after use?

Tags: jquery

I would like to make a button by creating new as every time user require. after user clicked on the button i would like to remove that.

for that i created this sting to html, but not working.

```
var tool = "";
            tool += '<div class="toolTip" id="toolTip">';
            tool +=    '<a href="#" class="btn btn-info saveText btn-xs copy">Save Text</a> </div>';

var rightButton =  $(tool).clone();

var i = 0;

var button = $('a.saveText');

$('div').mouseenter(function(){
    rightButton.appendTo('body');
})

button.click(function(e){
    console.log(++i);
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).remove();
})
```

what was the issue here?

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x2fokkh4/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Comment: FYI, jQuery has a [method to define an even that only triggers one](http://api.jquery.com/one/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Rewriting my original answer that was trying to "fix" this.
I think it would be more beneficial to see a more appropriate approach to what you're trying to do.

```
$('.content').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#button').show();
});

$('#button').click(function(e) {
    $(this).hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x2fokkh4/6/

Is there a requirement that you need to dynamically blow out and re-clone the button? If so, I will delete the answer. Otherwise, this is a much cleaner approach.

Comment: It should be noted a better approach might be to just show/hide the link.

Comment: @ClintPowell I agree. It should be noted there are much better ways to do this entirely. I was just trying to make it work within the original paradigm.

Comment: @Antiga, as knowledge I ask you a question, when i store a `dom` element to variable (which has click event), then re-appending to body, but it triggers multiple 'clicks` - what is the issue/correct oppoach? - if you don't mind.

Comment: Show/hide approach is fine as long as only one button is required, but the question doesn't inform us of that.

Comment: yes, i struggling with dynamic content issue. i have a button(static), it has to do the job to the dynamic contents. after i save the dynamic content again. now i clicking back to button it calls 3 times.. i could not find a solution for this.. that's what i trying to append the button using dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
var i = 0;
$('div').on('mouseenter', function(){
    $('<div class="toolTip" id="toolTip"><a href="#" class="btn btn-info saveText btn-xs copy">Save Text</a> </div>').appendTo('body');
})

$('body').on('click', '.saveText', function(e){
    console.log(++i);
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).remove();
})
```

jsfiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/j8x42Lbh/2/

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add inside the event  - you also might want to test if there already is a link available - or actually just show and hide the whole thing instead

```
$('div').mouseenter(function(){
    $(tool).appendTo('body');
    var button = $('a.saveText');
    button.click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent().remove(); // you want the whole thing to go
    });
});
```

or delegate the click:

```
$("body").on("click","a.saveText",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().remove();
});

$('div').mouseenter(function(){
   $(tool).appendTo('body');
});
```

```js
var tool = "";
   tool += '<div class="toolTip" id="toolTip">';
            tool +=    '<a href="#" class="btn btn-info saveText btn-xs copy">Save Text</a> </div>';
    


$('div').mouseenter(function(){
    $(tool).appendTo('body');
    var button = $('a.saveText');
    button.click(function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).parent().remove();
    });
});
```

```css
div.content{
    border:1px solid red;
    height:50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Comment: If `tool` is an HTML string, then why `$(tool).clone()`? `$(tool)` on its own will create a new instance.